# An accumulating superscript operator: translating $^i^+^1$ to $^{i+1}$ NOT to a double superscript ${{^i}^{+}+1}

Tags: unicode, superscripts

I like using Unicode characters in my input. They work great for making the text look more like the printed version, and consume less window space.  One glitch though, I cannot get the superscripts (or subscripts) right. There is always a double superscript problem.

What I seek is a macro such as `\SUP`, so that $X\SUP i \SUP + \SUP 1$ would be rewritten
as $X^{i+1}$

Here is an MWE: ```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\def\SUP{^}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{\SUP2}\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\SUP3}
\begin{document}
I can ask for $a$ squared plus $b$ squared to be equal to $c$ squared, 
  \[a²+b²=c²,\] 
and I can also ask for $a$ cubed plus $b$ cubed to be equal to $c$ cubed, 
  \[a³+b³= c³.\]
But, I cannot ask for $a$ raised to the twenty-third degree plus $b$ raised 
raised to the twenty-third degree to be equal to $c$ raised to the twenty-third 
degree, \[ a²³ + b²³ = b²³. \]
\end{document}
```

The output comes fine, e.g., here
[image]

However, the error messages are annoying

```
<argument> ^
        3
l.11     degree, \[ a²³
                      + b²³ = b²³. \]
I treat `x^1^2' essentially like `x^1{}^2'.
```

Comment: The superscript digits are scattered around Unicode. A lot of checks would be needed to take care of all UTF-8 combinations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\SUP` macro should be defined:

```
\def\SUP#1{\def\SUPt{#1}\futurelet\next\SUPa}
\def\SUPa{\ifx\next\SUP^\bgroup\SUPt\let\SUP=\SUPb\else^{\SUPt}\fi}
\def\SUPb#1{#1\futurelet\next\SUPc}
\def\SUPc{\ifx\next\SUP\else\egroup\fi}

%test:
$a\SUP2+b\SUP2=c\SUP2$

$a\SUP1\SUP2\SUP3$

\bye
```

Answer (score 8):

This works for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yossi_sup:
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nn
   { ([¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰]*) }
   { \c{sp}\cB\{\c{yossi_replace:n}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cE\} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \yossi_replace:n
 {
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__yossi_replace:n
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yossi_replace:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 } { {¹}{1}{²}{2}{³}{3}{⁴}{4}{⁵}{5}{⁶}{6}{⁷}{7}{⁸}{8}{⁹}{9}{⁰}{0} }
 }
\newunicodechar{¹}{\yossi_sup: ¹}
\newunicodechar{²}{\yossi_sup: ²}
\newunicodechar{³}{\yossi_sup: ³}
\newunicodechar{⁴}{\yossi_sup: ⁴}
\newunicodechar{⁵}{\yossi_sup: ⁵}
\newunicodechar{⁶}{\yossi_sup: ⁶}
\newunicodechar{⁷}{\yossi_sup: ⁷}
\newunicodechar{⁸}{\yossi_sup: ⁸}
\newunicodechar{⁹}{\yossi_sup: ⁹}
\newunicodechar{⁰}{\yossi_sup: ⁰}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$a²³ + b²³ = b²³$

$a¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰$

\end{document}
```

Each superscript digit is given a definition starting with `\yossi_sup:` This will start work: every subsequent character (including the starting one) that's in the list `¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰` is gathered until no more in the list follow. After that the whole lot is placed inside `^{...}` and the characters are replaced one by one with their standard counterpart.

It *might* be feasible also for `pdflatex`, but the main problem is that each superscript digit is either two or three byte long and the final replacement would be much more complex.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Similar to wipet's but adding extra expansion so `\SUP` can be hidden behind the expansion of the unicode characters.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed in old latex releases

\def\SUP#1{^\bgroup
#1\expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\next\expandafter\SUPb
\romannumeral`\^^@}
\def\SUPb{\ifx\next^\expandafter\SUPc\else\egroup\fi}
\def\SUPc#1#2{}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{\SUP2}\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\SUP3}
\begin{document}
I can ask for $a$ squared plus $b$ squared to be equal to $c$ squared, 
  \[a²+b²=c²,\] 
and I can also ask for $a$ cubed plus $b$ cubed to be equal to $c$ cubed, 
  \[a³+b³= c³.\]
But, I cannot ask for $a$ raised to the twenty-third degree plus $b$ raised 
raised to the twenty-third degree to be equal to $c$ raised to the twenty-third 
degree, \[ a²³ + b²³ = b²³. \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This could be a _very_ useful micropackage!!!

Comment: The full set is `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2070}{\SUP0}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B9}{\SUP1}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{\SUP2}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\SUP3}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2074}{\SUP4}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2075}{\SUP5}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2076}{\SUP6}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2077}{\SUP7}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2078}{\SUP8}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2079}{\SUP9}` ;-)

Comment: Well, _almost_ full: https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/superscripts-and-subscripts/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is basically a copy-and-paste of [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586136/38080) --- I just perused https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/superscripts-and-subscripts/, modified (I hope correctly) the `\romannumeral` black magic and extended this to subscripts.

I did not dare to edit David's answer... ;-)

This is without any guarantee that it will not eat your kittens --- the black magic part I really do not [grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

%
% Shamelessly copied from  @David Carlisle
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586136/38080
%

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed in old latex releases

\def\SUP#1{^\bgroup
#1\expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\next\expandafter\SUPb
\romannumeral`\^^@}
\def\SUPb{\ifx\next^\expandafter\SUPc\else\egroup\fi}
\def\SUPc#1#2{}
\def\SUB#1{_\bgroup
#1\expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\next\expandafter\SUBb
\romannumeral`\^^@}
\def\SUBb{\ifx\next_\expandafter\SUBc\else\egroup\fi}
\def\SUBc#1#2{}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2070}{\SUP0}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B9}{\SUP1}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{\SUP2}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\SUP3}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2074}{\SUP4}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2075}{\SUP5}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2076}{\SUP6}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2077}{\SUP7}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2078}{\SUP8}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2079}{\SUP9}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2071}{\SUP{i}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207A}{\SUP{{+}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207B}{\SUP{{-}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207C}{\SUP{{=}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207D}{\SUP{(}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207E}{\SUP{)}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207F}{\SUP{n}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2080}{\SUB0}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2081}{\SUB1}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2082}{\SUB2}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2083}{\SUB3}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2084}{\SUB4}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2085}{\SUB5}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2086}{\SUB6}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2087}{\SUB7}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2088}{\SUB8}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2089}{\SUB9}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{208A}{\SUB{{+}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{208B}{\SUB{{-}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{208C}{\SUB{{=}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{208D}{\SUB{(}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{208E}{\SUB{)}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2090}{\SUB{a}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2091}{\SUB{e}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2092}{\SUB{o}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2093}{\SUB{x}}

\begin{document}
I can ask for $a$ squared plus $b$ squared to be equal to $c$ squared,
  \[a²+b²=c²,\]
and I can also ask for $a$ cubed plus $b$ cubed to be equal to $c$ cubed,
  \[a³+b³= c³.\]
But, I cannot ask for $a$ raised to the twenty-third degree plus $b$ raised
raised to the twenty-third degree to be equal to $c$ raised to the twenty-third
degree, \[ a²³ + b²³ = b²³. \]
\[ x¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰pⁱⁿv⁺⁻z⁼k⁽¹⁾ \]
\[a¹₀₁₍₃₊₎\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(again, sorry for the awful antialiasing)